# Saving in entity framework

Tags: c#, entity-framework, savechanges

I have read [this](http://www.codeproject.com/Tips/309753/Repository-Pattern-with-Entity-Framework-4-1-and-C) article and still misunderstanding key moments. Don't we need call

```
_context.SaveChanges()
```

in every Delete/Update/... operations?

If I change property of any entity does `SaveChanges()` submitted result to database or I must manually set `EntityState.Modifyed`?

Here is my code:

```
public class Repository<T> : IRepository<T> 
    where T : class
{
    private IDbContext _context;

    public Repository(IDbContext context)
    {
        _context = context;
    }

    private IDbSet<T> DbSet
    {
        get
        {
            return _context.Set<T>();
        }
    }

    #region IRepository<T> Members

    public void Insert(T entity)
    {
        DbSet.Add(entity);
    }

    public void Delete(T entity)
    {
        DbSet.Remove(entity);
    }

    public IQueryable<T> SearchFor(Expression<Func<T, bool>> predicate)
    {
        return DbSet.Where(predicate);
    }

    public IQueryable<T> GetAll()
    {
        return DbSet;
    }

    public T GetById(int id)
    {
        return DbSet.Find(id);
    }
    #endregion
}

public interface IDbContext
{
    IDbSet<T> Set<T>() where T : class;

    int SaveChanges();
    void Dispose();
}
```

Comment: You don't have to call `[... = EntityState.Modifyed]` every time.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You ask:

> Don't we need call
>       _context.SaveChanges()
>   in every Delete/Update/... operations?

No we don't. When calling  `Delete` we don't accually delete the entity - we *mark* it for deletion.

Same thing with `Update`, although you dont have to do anything other that make the changes you want to the entity. All properties (generated by the default template) will implement `INotifyPropertyChanged` so it knows when a entity is modified.

All entities (in database first - autogenerated by defullt template) have a `State` property. This property is maintained by the `ObjectContext` as long as the chages take place within the scope of the ObjectEntity.

e.g.

```
Customer c;
using(var context = new MyEntityContext())
{
  c = context.Customer.FirstOrDefault(); //state is now Unchanged
  c.Name = "new name"; // this set the State to Modified
 //context.SaveChanges(); // will persist the data to the store, and set the State back to unchaged
}

//if we look at our customer outside the scope of our context
//it's State will be Detacth
Console.WriteLine(c.State);
```

Then you call `SaveChanges` all entites that have a state of `Added` `Deleted` or `Modified` will have their changes persisted to the database *in a local transaction*

**EDIT**

If an entity is marked for deletion, and you try to modify it - you will get an `InvalidOperationException`

Comment: so i need call Repository.GetAll().SaveChanges() to submit changes.Does I can still query deleted items (marked as deleted)?

Comment: yes you need to be able to call `Savechanges`. Definitely. I think you could still query an item that is marked for deletion, although i would not advice it - I don't think an entity can go from `Deleted` to `Modified`

Comment: I updated my answer. You get an exception if you try to modify an entity that is marked for deletion.

Answer (score 2):

You can perform many changes in your in-memory context,
such as inserts, updates and deletes.
Once you call SaveCahnges() all the changes you've made will be saved
in the DB at a single transaction.
This means that eiteher they are all submited, or none of them
in case of an error.

Comment: so must I implement SaveChanges method in IRepository ?

Comment: I'm not sure why you would want to wrap the context with your repository class. you can work with the context directly. e.g. context.Cars.AddObject(new Car()) , etc...